Open new view and close the current one in a NavigationStack
So far I'm using this solution:
iOS SwiftUI - NavigationLink open new view and close the current one
but I'm trying to do this with NaviationStack because it would make navigation less complicated overall.
This is the complete code to copy/paste:
struct NavStack: View {
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path){
            
            VStack(spacing: 40){
      
                Text("Start screen")
                
                Text("Login")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        path.append("Login")
                    }

            }
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self){ selection in
                if(selection == "Login"){
                    LoginScreen(path: $path)
                }else if(selection == "CreateAccount"){
                    CreateAccount(path: $path)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct LoginScreen: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    func closeThisView(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 40){

            Text("Login screen")
            
            Text("No account? Create account")
                .onTapGesture {
                    path.append("CreateAccount")
                    closeThisView()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct CreateAccount: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    func closeThisView(){

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 40){

            Text("Create account screen")
            
            Text("Have account? Login")
                .onTapGesture {
                    path.append("Login")
                    closeThisView()
                }
        }
    }
}

Technically it works, but not as expected. I want the new view to be opened and then the previous one closed in "the background". But what this code does is it first closes the current view and then, after around half a second the new view gets opened.
Is there a way to fix this?
